# Testing Spring boot customer actuator endpoint

Tags: spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-test

I created a autoconfigure project for spring boot which includes creation and configuration of custom actuator endpoints. I tried to test the endpoints using @SpringBootTest

### But the application failed to start with this error.

```
Web application could not be started as there was no org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.ServletWebServerFactory bean defined in the context.

Action:

Check your application's dependencies for a supported servlet web server.
Check the configured web application type.
```

Test Code:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.EndpointAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.TestConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate;
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.server.LocalServerPort;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
                properties = {"management.info.env.enabled=true" , "management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=info, health"},
                classes = {EndpointAutoConfiguration.class, StatusEndpointTest.TestConfig.class})
public class StatusEndpointTest {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate;

    @Test
    public void testStatusEndpoint() {
        ResponseEntity<String> response = testRestTemplate.getForEntity(
                "http://localhost:" + port + "/actuator/status", String.class);

        assertThat(response.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful()).isTrue();
        assertThat(response.getBody()).isNotNull();
    }

    @TestConfiguration
    public static class TestConfig {
        @Bean
        public TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate() {
            return new TestRestTemplate();
        }

    }
}
```

What am i missing here? The project is autoconfiguraiton module and I was able to include my project in a spring boot sample application and the custom endpoint is working fine. Can you pls help with the test? I want to hit the endpoint and get the response and don't want to mock the endpoint.
I am using spring boot version 3.1.5